# Define a variable based on a number n

Tags: r, dataframe, variables, naming-conventions

I have a series of three models I want to analyze with the same code in R. I would like to define `n = 1` at the beginning of my code, and then automatically have `est <- est1` along with other variables as written below. I feel that I need something opposite of the `assign()` function.

So defining n as 1, 2, or 3, for example:

```
n = 1
```

Would result in this:

```
est <- est1
fit <- fit1
vars <- model1vars
name <- 'Model_1'
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `get`

```
get(paste0('est', n))
```

If we need to extract all, create a pattern to match for object names by using `paste`, use that in `ls`, get the values of all objects with `mget` in a `list`

```
nm1 <- c("est", "fit", "model", "Model")
pat <- paste0("^(", paste(nm1, collapse = "|"), ")_?", n)
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = pat))
```